# Скорость вычислений в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я обучаю олимпиадному программированию на языках Python и C++.

Сейчас занимаюсь поиском способов ускорить долгие вычисления на Python.

Я тестировал одинаковые алгоритмы вычислений в двумерных массивах в C++ и Python и в отдельных случаях Python работал медленнее более чем в 50 раз, а для олимпиадного программирования очень важна скорость, т. к. на задачах стоит ограничение на общую длительность работы программы.

Вопрос: какие есть способы повышения скорости обработки двумерных списков в Python используя **только встроенные библиотеки**?

Comment: А можете привести в вопросе пример алгоритма на с++ и питоне, который при одном результате имеет такую разницу по выполнению?

Comment: А разве на олимпиадах не дают разные ограничения по времени для разных языков?

Comment: В Питоне есть режим компиляции в нативный код. Полученный в результате компиляции код должен быть не сильно медленнее С++ кода. Во всяком случае не в 50 раз медленнее.

Comment: @gil9red, вот вам пример: `a = np.random.rand(1000, 1000); %timeit a.sum(); %timeit sum(i for x in a for i in x)` - Numpy написан на `C`. У меня разница в ~215 раз  ;)

Comment: @pepsicoca1 а как включить этот режим?

Comment: @Борис Честно говоря, я с Питоном не работаю. По-моим понятиям есть отдельный компилятор из Питона в нативный код. То есть это не режим интерпретатора, а отдельный компилятор. Погуглите, материалов на эту тему должно быть много. Питон это сейчас мейнстрим. Или же в Visual Studio должен быть ключ, который генерирует нативный код хотя бы для архитектуры х86.

Comment: Есть более быстрый Cython. Вот его описание: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cython#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

## В чем проблема

Python в его стандартной реализации CPython при запуске и работе переживает компиляцию и интерпретацию.

### Компиляция

При запуске Python кода происходит обработка кода интерпретатором, после чего преобразуется в байт-код. Такой код не обрабатывается процессором напрямую, но меньше весит. Он сохраняется в pyc или оперативной памяти. После чего начинается следующий этап.

### Интерпретация

Получившийся байт код поступает на выполнение в виртуальную машину CPython. А уже данный инструмент в свою очередь взаимодействует с процессором. То есть, байт код переходит в нативный, который может быть напрямую обработан процессором.

Из-за такой системы обработки затрудняются оптимизации кода, код на ходу интерпретируется и потому работает медленнее.

## Решение

### JIT компиляция

JIT компиляция - вид компиляции, при которой часто выполняемые куски кода компилируются в машинный код и кэшируются. Можно не внося изменения в код, ускорить его работу такими оптимизациями в интерпретаторе.

### PyPy

У питона есть множество реализаций и даже семейств реализаций. Во многих из них используется другой механизм обработки кода. Одна реализаций Python - PyPy. Эта реализация поддерживает JIT компиляцию. Я не очень разбираюсь в тонкостях, но знаю, что данная реализация универсальна, поскольку работает не с конкретным языком программирования, а байт кодом. То есть автоматически добавляет jit к любому компилятору.

PyPy сочетает компилятор семейства RPython с статической типизацией и JIT.

### Если нужно попроще

Существует библиотека Numba. С помощью нее можно компилировать в машинный код отдельные фрагменты кода и ускорить многократные повторения. Подробное описание и документацию можете загуглить.

### "Дергание" C из Python

Библитека numpy, написанная на C и C++ может многократно ускорить работу с массивами. Нужно лишь конвертировать соответствующий массив в numpy.array. Подробную документацию также можете загуглить.

## Итог

Ускорить питон можно как использованием других реализаций (PyPy и другие), так и с помощью библиотек (numba, numpy), что вам и требовалось.

Comment: Наглядных примеров бы, было бы супер